# Passing data from main form to usercontrol on the child form

Tags: c#, forms

I'm trying to pass a List to the UserControl (UC) in the child form to populate a combobox on this UC. I tried to declare a public property on a UC and pass a data from the MainForm to it to populate a data.
Like this:

**Main form**

```
private void OpenChildForm()
{
     ChildForm cf = new ChildForm(myList); // list is global one
     UserControl uc = new UserControl();
     cf.Show();
     uc.InitializeLookup(myList);
}
```

**Child form**

```
public List<string> SelectedItems { get; set; }
public void InitializeLookup(List<string> listItems)
{
     SelectedItems = listItems.Select(s => s.ZipCode)
                              .Distinct()
                              .ToList();
}
```

Wherever I'm attempting to access the SelectedItems, it becomes empty, disregardless, where I'm doing this: either in UserControl_Load event handler, or in UserControl_Paint event hadler. Is there any way to keep this List in memory? I don't want to save/load it from file.

Thanks in an advance.

Comment: You simply want myList to pass on child form right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OpenChildForm() method there is no relationship between cf and uc objects. Why are you creating instance of UserControl in this method?
Usercontrol is a part of ChildForm, so pass a selecteditemlist from Main form to child form and during ChildForm's load event assign selecteditemlist to Usercontrol.